# Invalid year in a date field in MS Access

Tags: date, ms-access

I have some invalid dates in my Access database which are considered valid by Access because technically these are just future dates. So some years were entered as "11/20/3014" or "12/01/4015" instead of "11/20/2014" or "12/01/2015" respectively. Unfortunately Access considers them valid. I used this query to identify the erroneous dates:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE YEAR(Table1.[DateField]) > YEAR(Now);
```

I wanted to use an update query to fix those dates and was wondering if there is a way to include logic to cover a number of combinations into an Access query. I wanted something like

```
If Year(DateField) starts with "3" then use "2" instead of "3" etc.
```

Can anyone please help me build the update query?

Comment: After you fix the data, add a Validation Rule for `DateField` to reject future dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
UPDATE 
    Table1 
SET 
    [DateField] = DateSerial(2000 + Year([DateField]) Mod 100, Month([DateField]), Day([DateField]))
WHERE 
    YEAR([DateField]) > YEAR(Now);
```

Comment: Nice solution, beat me to it.